# Validate User email to match one of two regex's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, email

In my Rails app college students with either @berkeley.edu or @uw.edu email addresses can register. I have the regex for validating both ready but since I need to check the email address the user enters to see which one it matches I think I need to create one regex, but I don't know how. Here are my two regex's:

```
berkeley_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@berkeley\.edu\z/i
uw_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@uw\.edu\z/i
```

And my validate:

```
validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => {:with => berkeley_regex}
```

Now, what would the regex to check against both but only match against one look like?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "check against both but only match against one"?  Eg with some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just validate against something like `/\A[\w+\-.]+@(berkeley|uw)\.edu\z/i` and be done with it? If you really need to later determine which it is, make a method that just checks the back part, or returns the match, or whatever...

Answer (score 0):

First I think your regex should be changed from `[\w+\-.]` to `[\w+\-\.]`

The validation could be

```
validates :email, format: { with: "\A#{berkely_regex}|#{uw_regex}\z/i" }
```

but you'll need to remove the flags ( `\A`, `\z`, `/i` ) from the vartiables